# Есть ли какое-то событие в unity, сопровождающее появление на сцене обьекта?

Tags: unity3d

Есть ли какое-то событие в unity когда на сцене появляется обьект? Awake работает только, когда Active обьекта = true, а мне нужно, чтобы работала даже, когда Active = false.

Comment: Что значит с "и в выключенном состоянии"? Объясните весь принцип в вопросе и всю логику

Comment: Равным событием является не только появление, но и спавн. Тот кто спавнит вполне может отчитаться об этом. Unity тут вообще не причем.